# Switch another navigation programmatically swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I ignore storyboard and create `UINavigationController` in `AppDelegate.swift`

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: HomeController(collectionViewLayout: layout))//make the ViewController class to be the root

    return true
}
```

I have `leftBarButton` which switches to another `UINavigationController` or `UICollectionViewController`(according to your advice)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let parentMenuButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 34, height: 34))
    parentMenuButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.menuButtonOnClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: parentMenuButton)
}

@objc func menuButtonOnClicked(){
    print("menuButtonOnClicked button is pressed")
}
```

[image]

How can I achieve this programmatically?(switch another navigation area by pressing menu button)

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let secondViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
```

Error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard () doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'SecondViewController''

I create SecondViewController:

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

}
```

Is there a way to do it without messing with storyboard?(only programatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call push method in your `menuButtonOnClicked()`

```
 @objc func menuButtonOnClicked(){
    print("menuButtonOnClicked button is pressed")
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let secondViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as SecondViewController
    self.navigationController.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
    }
```

[image]

Comment: your code not working according to xcode advice, I change your code to question

Comment: you need to set identifier of your viewController.. check the updated answer just go in your storyboard give the class and storyboard id `SecondViewController`

Comment: Is there a way to do it without messing with storyboard?(Updated question)

Comment: no you can't :( you need to set it in interface builder