# How can I switch programmatically between view controllers that are not on the same storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to switch between a view controller (that is coded programmatically) to a `ViewController` with the UI Elements on the storyboard.

I am trying to switch between a `HomeController` to a `TabBarController` using a button but by pressing the button it switches to a dark screen. I would be glad if some of you could help me out.

Here is my code:

```
var welcomeLabel: UIButton = {

let label = UIButton()

label.tintColor = .white

label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

label.alpha = 0

label.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleLogin), for: .touchUpInside)

return label

}()

...............

@objc func handleLogin() {

navigationController?.show(TabBarController(), sender: Any?.self)

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switch another navigation programmatically swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53447780/switch-another-navigation-programmatically-swift)

Answer (score 0):

use this code if you're pushing view from `NavigationController`

```
navigationController?.pushViewController("YourViewController", animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in following way

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Your_storyboard", bundle: nil)
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Your_View_controller") as! Your_View_controller
```

Now to present

```
self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Or through navigation controller

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil) // Give the name .e.g if you have the different story board name
    let YourNextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "your story board identifier") as! StoryBoardName/ClassName
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(YourNextViewController, animated: true)
   //Or if you want to present viewController
    self.present(YourNextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

Comment: you copied my answer bro, before posting an answer, you should have a look on other answers before.